# asp.net tryint to write to file on server

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to write to a file on my website. But when trying to open the file using this line:
fileName = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "lala.htm";

I get this exception:
(It gets to the right path, but still doesn't allow me to write to it)

Access to the path '**d:\DZHosts\LocalUser\asafz83\www.asafz83.somee.com\lala.htm**' is denied.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'd:\DZHosts\LocalUser\asafz83\www.asafz83.somee.com\lala.htm' is denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'd:\DZHosts\LocalUser\asafz83\www.asafz83.somee.com\lala.htm' is denied.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +7716639
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +1162
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options) +65
   System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append) +62
   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) +58
   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append) +33
   Class1.HTTPFilter.Init(HttpApplication context) in C:\Documents and Settings\אסף אזולאי\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WebSite6\Class1\httpFilter.cs:50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +65
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModules() +43
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +729
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +298
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +289

HELP PLEASE...
ANYONE...

Comment: Please reformat the code in your question (e.g. `fileName = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "lala.htm";` It would make it much more readable. And as @Darin Dimitrov suggests, the solution seems to be in the exception/question?!?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you read the exception message:

> ASP.NET is not authorized to access
> the requested resource. Consider
> granting access rights to the resource
> to the ASP.NET request identity.
> ASP.NET has a base process identity
> (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5
> or Network Service on IIS 6) that is
> used if the application is not
> impersonating. If the application is
> impersonating via , the identity will
> be the anonymous user (typically
> IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
> request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file,
> right-click the file in Explorer,
> choose "Properties" and select the
> Security tab. Click "Add" to add the
> appropriate user or group. Highlight
> the ASP.NET account, and check the
> boxes for the desired access.

So grant write permissions to the ASPNET account to the `d:\DZHosts\LocalUser\asafz83\www.asafz83.somee.com` folder.

Comment: I am not stupid. there is no option to grant it the right access as he said in the 2nd paragraph you were wise enought to quote. 
Someone who knnow s how to solve this please...

Comment: I must be missing something.  Why is it not an option for you to grant write access to the file for the ASP.NET identity?

Comment: @asaf, do you have administrative privileges on the target machine?

Comment: No Darin, it is a free shared server.

Comment: Maybe, that's the problem, you don't have sufficient privileges to grant write access. You will need to ask your hosting provider in this case to do it for you.

Comment: I asked him and he told me that all the files uploaded to the server have, by default, write permission.  How can I grant permissions to the ASPNET account?

Comment: When he replied to you that all files have write permission by default, ask him to which account those write permissions are applied. Explain that you need to have write permissions to the `ASPNET` account (IIS 5) or `Network Service` account (IIS 6) or any custom account that your provider might have configured for the application pool that your applications is running under. Also send him the exception message as a proof that the folder has no write permissions for the account that is used by IIS to execute your application.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to do that.